# Use Drupal 6 module as a service in another module

Tags: drupal

I need to get back results and use it from another module, I would like to use module as a service in another module.
As I could instanciate an object in another object in php.
I don't know if someone can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 6 is not that much OOP oriented - you don't have something like services and service container.

On other hand you can use functions from any other module. Just find out what function you need and call it. And don't forget to add that other module as dependence for your module.